# How to create sub-roles of roles in ASP.NET using MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create sub roles of roles using Identity in MVC 5 but I am unable to find any way to do so.
What I Want to achieve is :

```
     A-----------B-----------C
                 |
            B1 - B2 - B3
```

Here A ,B and C are three Main Roles and B1 , B2 and B3 are three sub-roles of B.
I have implemented just a single level roles but when it comes to multiple levels , I am unable to find any useful method.Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: A, b, b1, b2, b3 and c. What's wrong with them? Authentication doesn't care how you logically group them...

Comment: When registering a user , I would have two dropdowns,one for role and anither for sub  role.Sub role should be loaded upon the selection of the role.For eg., Departments and then Phy Dept ,Chem Dept and Maths Dept. .

Comment: Divide. That's your View Model. Your Model is what asp.net wants

Comment: OK , So I should store all the roles in a single level and while registering they should be divided and multiple roles should be assigned to a user .Please tell me if am getting right.Thanks.

Comment: Yes! You may also build subroles like a path to present them as a hierarchy.

Comment: Okay ! Thanks , I will try it out and revert back !

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I tried this way , but whenever I would have to add a new role , I would have to make some changes. Isn't there any custom role provider out there supporting role hierarchy.

Comment: Changes? What do you need them for? Build your full role name as B/B1/B1_b and so on. When you have to present your combos just fetch all roles, pick first _path_ part and populate 1st combo. To populate 2nd combo...fetch all roles and populate with roles that start with what in 1st combo. That's done. Do you need to add a role? No code changes. Of course don't put all this "logic" in your view, there is ViewModel for this.